# Windows Auto Complete Icon List

Tags: windows, git, bitbucket

Hi does anyone knows where is the list of Icons for Windows Auto-Complete?

Notice when you are typing in notepad, browser or anywhere in Windows OS.
There is some icons to select when you are typing a text.

I would like to know if where can we find this list.

for example i type bear, i can select a bear icon from the auto-complete.
[image]

or when i type pizza, there is a pizza icon that i can select.

[image]

anyway, just like to see the list of icons available for the auto-complete feature.

Thank you in advance

btw this icons can also be used in git commit and will show in pull request in bitbucket

Comment: How does this question have half of those tags?

Comment: ahh you can use the icons to your commits in git, and shows on bitbucket PRs..

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this link? it contains Windows Icons list

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font

Comment: the answer is useful, however this is not the one i am looking for.